# Avoid replicating DELETE statements in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-replication

Consider the following scenario:

One PC is running an Access database. An old legacy script will copy over all the contents from this Access database to a SQL Server (A) over LAN. But before it does this, it will delete all contents from the destination database, so it doesn't have to deal with existing records. Previously existing records are never altered.

On the SQL Server (A), replication is defined and it acts as a publisher. It will publish/replicate the data to SQL Server (B) over WAN.

This all works very well, but the only problem I'm facing is when there's a problem during the copying of contents to SQL Server (A), SQL Server (B) will be empty or missing records, even the records that were replicated a long time ago.

There are two solutions I've already considered:

- Adapt the legacy script to only copy over new records, since the updates are incremental of nature.
- Configure the replication to avoid DELETE statements.

The first solution is in this scenario not possible. The application is closed-source, and there's really nothing we can change.

The second solution would be ideal, but (A) would try to replicate records that already exist on (B), and I'm not quite sure how to handle that.

Surely there's a sound concept to this problem, I just haven't figured it out yet..

Answer (score 1):

In SSMS go to Replication -> Local Publications and right click on your publication and select Properties.  In the Publication Properties window click on 'Articles' and select the relevant article.  Go to "Article Properties" and select "Set Properties of Highlighted Table Article". In the article properties window, change the "DELETE delivery format" to "Do not replicate DELETE statements".
After the change click OK and you will see a prompt.  As the article property has been changed the subscriptions need to be reinitialized. Click "Mark for Reinitialization" which causes the snapshot to be applied to the subscriber.
In SSMS, navigate to Replication and right click and select "Launch Replication Monitor".  Go to your publication and click View Details to see the snapshot progress.

Comment: I've considered that, but if the database is emptied each time, and refilled again (with old AND new data), will the replication not attempt to replicate existing records next to new records?